# How to refactor and call a refactored hook properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm currently using Apollo's React hooks for GraphQL authentication.  I want to refactor a mutation so that I can use for all different logins like Google, Facebook, Twitter OAuth, etc.

```js
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import { CREATE_POST_MUTATION } from '../../graphql/mutation'

const [createPost, { loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_POST_MUTATION, {
    onCompleted: data => {
        navigation.navigate("StatusModal", {
            status: "postingSuccess",
            screen: "Posting",
            data,
        })
    },
    onError: data => {
        navigation.navigate("StatusModal", {
            status: "postingError",
            screen: "Posting",
        })
    },
})

const createPostHandler = async () => {
    const { title, price, description, address } = value && value

    try {
        await createPost({
            variables: {
                title,
                body: description,
                price: Number(price),
                location: location.toString(),
                address,
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
        navigation.navigate("StatusModal", {
            status: "postingError",
            screen: "Posting",
        })
    }
}

export { createPostHandler as default }
```

Calling the above code shows the error that the React hooks can only be called inside the body of a functional component. How do I make this re-usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks are running (can be executed) **only** in a "render flow" of a functional component, you can't **run** it in other context.

For reusing **you can define a function containing `useMutation` in external file**/exported function and call/run it in many functional components.

Maybe you're looking for custom hooks?